# Is there a way to add children components to functional stateless components that are called as functions?

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, components

I have a functional stateless component like so:

```
const Map = (props) => {
    ...
}
```

And I want to call it as a function inside of a container

```
{Map()}
```

Normally I know I can include children

```
<Map>
    <ChildComponent />
</Map>
```

Is there a way do the same thing while calling the component as a function?

Comment: Why do you want to call it as a function in the first place?

Comment: I think there was supposed to be some performance improvement I could get out of doing that. Looking at the given answer, I'd rather not do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I want to call it as a function*, yes you can. But then you will have to restructure your components and it will come at come cost. You cannot use them interchangeably without some compromises.

Following is a sample:

```js
const Parent = function(props){
  return (
    <div>
      <h3> This is Parent</h3>
      {
        Array.isArray(props.children) ? 
          props.children.map(x => typeof(x) === 'function' ? x() : x) : 
          null
      }
     </div>
  )
}

const Child = function(props){
  return (
    <p>This is Child! My name is {props.name}</p>
  )
}

let JSX = Parent({
  children: [
    Child.bind(null, {name: 'foo'}),
    Child.bind(null, {name: 'Bar'})
  ]
});
ReactDOM.render(JSX, document.getElementById('content'));

let JSX2 = (
  <Parent>
    <Child name='Jon'/>
  </Parent>
)

ReactDOM.render(JSX2, document.getElementById('content2'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='content'></div>
<hr/>
<div id='content2'></div>
```

Comment: **Note:** This is a simulation on how we can use SFC as a function as well. If you think there is anything *inappropriate/ incorrect/ not required*, please comment along with your vote. Have a good day. :-)

Comment: Accepted answer, but will probably just call component using JSX.

Comment: I guess thats the ideal way. :-)